will the usage of BMS eliminate the change over functionality while charging A LIPO pack?
I am using a BMS in project, which is this one. As can be seen from the picture, it has common input output terminals. Now suppose I have connected the load to those terminals and then want to charge the battery. At this point I have to connect the charger to the same output terminals. It means, while charging, The load and the BMS battery pack is parallel to the charger. Now the questions is Will the BMS automatically detect the charger and cutting the load off from the battery and then charge the battery? because at the same time charging and discharging is not a good idea as far as I know. For a battery without BMS, I know I can achieve this "change over" functionality using a P channel MOSFET, But if I Use a BMS will that eliminate the design of such a changing over mechanism?

You can't charge and discharge a battery at the same time.  However, you can run the end equipment while charging the battery, both from the adapter.  Some charger manufacturers call this "power path" management (e.g. any cellphone).  I doubt your BMS has a function to cut off the load while charging, but at first glance I didn't see a detailed spec sheet for the product on the Amazon page.  Without that, I would avoid that product like the plague because charging and protecting lithium batteries is serious business, best not to have unknowns in the mix.

The BMS does not appear to include an automatic load disconnect feature during charging based on the description.

@JohnD then what if I run the load and charge the battery by connecting both parallel to the charger? will that be an issue?

@aud098 That's a system question that depends on the voltage range of your load, the charger capabilities (e.g. to measure the battery vs. the load current) and other variables.  Impossible to answer without a lot more details.

@JohnD assuming it is a fast charger, and the load will support ALL the voltage ranges provided by the charger. Also the charger is powerful enough to supply current to both battery and the load simultanously. In that case will it be an issue if i connect them in such manner? Here my main confusion is when I charge the battery, since the load is still connected to the battery, does it charge and discharge the battery at the same time hence harming the battery?

The charger has to have the ability to measure, regulate and control the battery charge current independent of the load current, so you can't just parallel the battery, charger and load without consideration to those factors.
